# How to call JSP from Java stand-alone program

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

How can I call a `JSP` file from a Java application, and pass to it a Java Bean, so that as a result I can get a rendered `HTML` code as output.
The Java program is a stand-alone application, that runs by someone. No servlet please.

Comment: You need to submit a http get request, e.g. using Apache HttpClient: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Comment: will I able to pass Java bean?

Comment: Can Servlets be avoided at all? Are JSPs not compiled to servlets? or are there other compilers as well?

Comment: I'm not Java developer that's I'm asking. I need as result HTML as a string in output. Java application that's will use that jsp (as template) stand-alone app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Non-Servlet environment & it is a stand-alone application so I think you can use any String template such as Velocity, FreeMaker instead of using JSP.

Comment: can you please provide a few lines of code how to call those template with passing java bean?

Comment: Why do you need JavaBean? JavaBean is used in JSP only. If you don't use JSP -> don't use JavaBean

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv: Showing examples of general Velocity or FreeMarker usage would be too long for a SO answer. Just google to find a tutorial, read some doc and then come back here with more precise questions

Answer (score 1):

A JSP is a servlet too. So you need all those Java EE classes, and hence also an implementation by some provider (Java EE container). You could use [**jetty**](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) as an embedded Java EE container.

You can then via URL get the generated HTML page.

If you want minimal JSP functionality, more a scriptable HTML **template** engine,
look at StringTemplate or Velocity or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly a complement to @AppsLandia's answer.

Even if it *looks like* a template engine, JSP is **not**. JSP files are first translated into Java source servlets and then compiled to .class normal servlets. That's the reason why they cannot be used outside of a web application running on a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty or...

Velocity and FreeMarker *can* be used in web applications, but they **are** general template engines, so you should have a look to them.